# Error creating a bean in Spring Mvc Web Application

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, apache-httpclient-4.x

I receive the following error when trying to accessing the jsp page I have created.  Im using RAD and Websphere 8 for this application.  Im not sure which code to post here so just posting the error for now. Please help!

```
    [6/18/14 11:15:18:871 CDT] 00000029 DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oicClaimEntryControlloer' defined in file [C:\RAD\OICRewriteNew1\OICWeb\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\gov\usps\oic\controller\OicClaimEntryControlloer.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1649)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:748)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:633)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1134)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1632)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.access$400(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1567)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5277)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5493)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl._startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1334)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fineGrainUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1539)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:701)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:575)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1936)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1445)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:657)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.save(ConfigServiceImpl.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1334)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:77)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:564)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:564)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    ... 99 more
```

Comment: do you have org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod in your classpath ?

Comment: Yes, I do have the following jars in my class path.  commons-codec, fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar, httpclient-4.3.3, httpclient-cache-4.3.3, httpcore, and httpmime.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Problem was the version of HTTPClient. I guess they changed the directories in the new version. In version 3 HttpMethod class was under org.apache.common.httpclient and in version 4 its under org.apache.httpclient. so after downloading the older version i was able to fix the problem. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Problem was the version of HTTPClient. I guess they changed the directories in the new version. In version 3 HttpMethod class was under org.apache.common.httpclient and in version 4 its under org.apache.httpclient. so after downloading the older version i was able to fix the problem. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the error log it appears that you don't have the proper jar for org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod on the classpath. Is it not included in your war file?

Comment: Yes, I do have the following jars in my class path.  commons-codec, fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar, httpclient-4.3.3, httpclient-cache-4.3.3, httpcore, and httpmime.